# What is the default order of search result if search parameters absent in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What is default order of index for filtered results (and for all results)? By last update? By date of indexed? I tried to get all the documents from my index, but I could not figure out what is the default sort order.

Answer (score 1):

Default sort order is _score, but score is always `1` when you do not specify a search query. Its then more or less random with score being `1`. You still get consistent results as far as I remember. You have the "same" when you get results in SQL but don't specify `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks anyway. If all the results have same score then what way elasticsearch order the result?

Comment: It will come randomly as in case of SQL server when you do not provide order by.